# How to define a slot in a Vue.js template when using render function?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

When defining a slot in a Vue.js component template using regular old HTML, it's as simple as this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello, I am a template!</h1>
    <slot name="my_slot"></slot>
</div>
```

And it can be activated like so when using the template in your page:

```
<my-template>
    <template slot="my_slot">
        <p>Slot content.</p>
    </template>
</my-template>
```

Which should output something like:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello, I am a template!</h1>
    <p>Slot content.</p>
</div>
```

However, my situation requires that I define my component template using the render function which means the template DOM needs to be set up using nested calls to the createElement function. So my original template definition would now look something like this:

```
h('div', {}, [
    h('h1', {
        domProps:{
            innerHTML: "Hello, I am a template!"
        }
    }, []),
    h('slot', {
        attrs:{
            name: "my_slot"
        }
    }, [])
])
```

However this doesn't work for me. I'm assuming it's because 'slot' isn't a valid html tag but I can't seem to find any clear answer on this specific subject. How can I correctly define slots in a Vue.js component template when using the render function?

Comment: There is an in depth article here on [how to use scoped slots with render functions](https://cpectre.com/blog/posts/vue-scoped-slots-with-render-functions). This is up to date with vue 3 since most of the answers here use vue 2

Comment: NOTE: the above link is broken here is an article [how to use scoped slots with render functions](https://geistjs.com/blog/vue/vue-scoped-slots-with-render-functions) and I added some info to this on the vue docs [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function#scoped-slots)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots)

```
h('div', {}, [
    h('h1', {
        domProps:{
            innerHTML: "Hello, I am a template!"
        }
    }, []),
    this.$slots.my_slot
])
```

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting:
    TypeError: this.$slots.my_slot is not a function

Comment: oh right, only scoped slots are functions. corrected answer

Comment: Ah, that worked! But in fact I think I actually need to use scoped slots. I used this:

`this.$scopedSlots.header_buttons({
 props: this.props
})`

and it worked. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
h('div', {}, [
    h('h1', {
        domProps:{
            innerHTML: "Hello, I am a template!"
        }
    }, []),
    h('div', {
        slot: 'my_slot'
    }, [])
])
```

and it works.

Comment: What is your proposed change?